# JavaScript Scroll Script - Fires in test, not on dev site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, content-management-system

My script to replace the logo upon scroll works here in the test 'http://jsfiddle.net/timsalabim/opek5mtz/`

```
<!-- Logo Scroll -->

var img = document.querySelector('.logo_h__img img'); // get the element
img.dataset.orig = img.src; // dataset 
document.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) { // add the event listener
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0) { // check the scroll position
        img.src = img.dataset.scroll; // set the scroll image
    } else {
        img.src = img.dataset.orig; // set the original image back
    }
});
```

It does not work when implemented exactly the same way in to the website, I think I have tested it correctly and it is firing too....

I put the script in to my site in the `<head>  </head>` tags located in the header.php file (Wordpress website) inside these tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    </script>
```

I also didn't forget to add this section the image tag:

```
data-scroll="http://"
```

Is it possible that the navigation is set up in a way that the logo which is nested next to it doesn't recognise a scroll?

**** UPDATE ****
Here is my dev site: http://dev.greenlabit.com.au/Test/

Comment: What file is your javascript located in on the site?

Comment: You'll have to show us _how_ you implemented it into your site. Linking us to an unmodified demo theme doesn't provide enough information for us to be able to help you with your problem.

Comment: Updated and showed how implemented. I will put in a live dev site now if needed.

Comment: On that desired page, if you view the source do you see the Javascript in the source?

Comment: Yes. It appears correctly as above too.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some other JS and got it to work!
It stopped functioning when the fixed navigation bar was in use.

Thank you for all of your help.